# Update elements of array according to other array in one line?

Tags: python

I have two arrays called y and R(same dimensions). R consists of 1 and 0's. I am trying to change y's elements to 0 if according element of R is 0, otherwise keep it same.
I attempted this one line:

```
y=[0 for a in y if for b in r if b==0]
```

but it says invalid syntax. How should I change it?

Comment: `y = [b and a for b, a in zip(r, y)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate one list, accessing the other list by index:

```
y = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
R = [0,0,1,1,0,1]

res = [ 0 if R[i] == 0 else a for i, a in enumerate(y) ]
#=> [0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7]
```

Or

```
[ 0 if r == 0 else y[i] for i, r in enumerate(R) ]
#=> [0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7]
```

---

Alternative using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7])
R = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1])

print(y * R)
#=> [0 0 4 5 0 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your list comprehension this way:

```
y = [0 if j == 0 else i for i, j in zip(y, R)]
```

Your invalid sintax error comes from the `for` immediately after the `if`, it does not mean anything for the interpreter.

Comment: yes, I know "for if" is a non-sense but I wondered maybe there is a similar version for that phrase.

Comment: I don't know, I also cannot understand what you hoped to achieve with that sintax. `if` keyword must be followed by a statement which can be evaluated as true or false (see [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans)) otherwise is syntax error.